# What is the purpose of "meaning-in-context" tag?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

I just noticed that we have a [meaning-in-context](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) tag. As of now the tag has no usage guidance.

Only two questions are tagged with this tag and one of the is closed as off-topic. The other queston is [¿Es “hueco” una traducción correcta para “gap” de datos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20705/5481). I understand that this asks for the best choice of a word in a given context, but that is what this kind of questions are supposed to do, like in questions with [seleccion-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seleccion-de-palabras), for which you'll pick the best choice for a word, based on their meaning and connotations in a given context.

The meaning of "Meaning in context" should be very obvious but, shouldn't everything have a meaning in a given context after all? Why would we need a tag then to state the obvious?

I mean, isn't "meaning in context" kind of truism? We wouldn't make sense of a "meaning without context" (a tag which we don't have) because that would be like listing all possible meanings of a word.

I'm also trying to think of **the use case for this tag**: somebody trying to list all questions related to "meaning in a context". I can't get my head around what we are trying to tag with this tag.

Since the tag has no usage guidance, let's discuss if we need this tag and what for, and then edit its excerpt (if applicable) to match the needs of the site for such tag.

Comment: @walen I agree. Knowing how things are in Meta I'll leave some time to see if we can get some answers. After a while, if there is no answer still proposing so, I'll leave my own answer proposing to delete this tag. Then, depending on votes on answers we'll proceed either to update the usage guidance for this tag (and possible retagging questions with it) or to delete the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag is unnecessary, because it is redundant with the necessity of providing a context when you are asking for the meaning or connotations of a word<sup>1</sup>. Thus, **it should be deleted**.

1. There is no real use case for searching questions in which we ask for the meaning of a word in a context. There are actually tags for certain contexts (like [informática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inform%c3%a1tica) or [comida](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comida)) which will make a more efficient and easier search of "questions asking for a word meaning when providing a context".
2. In spite of being some sort of truism, the tag's usage is not intuitive. There is currently no usage guidance. The lack of it can illustrate that it is difficult to explain what is it for and how to use it.
3. Other Language-related stacks might be benefiting from this tag, but that doesn't mean it will be the case for our particular stack. They saw it as a useful tool, but for us, for the reasons listed above, it is not the case.

Therefore, I propose to delete it.

---

<sub>1: Otherwise you would be asking for "all possible meanings of a word", a type of question that is likely to be off-topic either for allowing multiple valid answers or because it would just require a dictionary search to answer the question. Only few true good questions like this will show up, and they are likely to be handled as an exception case (like in a wiki type of answer).</sub>

Comment: Seeing that there is only one answer with one downvote, I'm going to move this discussion forward with another option.

Comment: Relevant related post: [How do you determine when a tag is bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/3961519): 1- tag implies no clearly defined meaning  2- tag has a clearly defined meaning, but is still misused often 3-  tag can be replaced with a combination of more generic tags

Comment: Han pasado unos cuantos días, sugiero marcar esta respuesta como aceptada y proceder con la eliminación de la etiqueta.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for asking!

I proposed [meaning-in-context](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) because have found it to be a [helpful tag at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context):

> for questions about the meaning of a longer passage of English. A SPECIFIC CONCERN must be emphasized.

To compare, [ELU's "meaning" tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning):

> for questions related to definitions and nuances of meaning of a word or phrase.

Example of a question that wouldn't need "meaning-in-context": [¿Qué diferencia hay entre "ayudar" y "coadyuvar"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25569/9385)

Example of a question that *would* benefit from "meaning-in-context": [Other meanings of "raspado" (aside from the gastronomic)?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25633/9385) (and I have tentatively added the tag)

There are other questions for which [meaning-in-context](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) could be a helpful tag.  If I've been waiting a bit before adding the new tag to more questions, it's at least partly because I wanted to allow time for objections.  So please don't take my moving slowly with that as an indication that there are only two questions out there that this proposed new tag would fit.

Comment: I've removed the parts about the tag [tag:acepción], since they are completely unrelated to the question. Please mention those things in the proper places.

Comment: Regarding the tag, I cannot see how it is useful and gives value to group questions with it. In [this Meta post in ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9421/37429) I see they define it quite differently: _for questions of understanding of parts of longer texts_. As is now and have been used by you to tag 3 questions, I think [tag:vocabulario-técnico] completely covers the needs.

Comment: I think that you need to elaborate much more about why those questions would benefit or not of the tag. You just said "this one would, this wouldn't", but ** you are not explaining why**, which is the whole point of this discussion. Also, " questions about the meaning of a **longer** passage" - "longer" than what? Maybe could be a good idea to hint or clarify a usage guide for this tag. And probably we would need to see how it compares to other tags like "vocabulario-tecnico" (which states a_context_), "significado" (Significado de una palabra ya sea suelta o dentro de un contexto dado)

Comment: Also, I have to praise that you acknowledged that is better to discuss the tag before proceeding to tag more questions. If you have other questions that you think would benefit from this tag, feel free to link the in your answer, so it helps illustrating and clarifying the purposed usage of the tag.